# WinAppDriver vs LeanFT

Tags: java, selenium, appium, winappdriver

I am currently using LeanFT for a windows based application automation and evaluating WinAppDriver for eliminating the license cost involved for the former. Anyone knows of any shortcomings of this option of going for WinAppDriver on a very high level. My application is hosted on Win2016 server and its currently supported by WinAppDriver too just like Windows 10. The application is currently being accessed thru a citrix server and that gives a major automation challenge while using LeanFT itself. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I sadly cannot suggest Winappdriver at this time since its development has been halted by Microsoft for the last 8-9 months:

https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1103

Still no word on the future of the project from Microsoft.